# O Facebook aprovará um app Android com facebook4j?

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook

Eu decidi utilizar a biblioteca facebook4j por ela ser mais fácil para integração e até para o próprio desenvolvimento, na minha opinião.

A minha dúvida é: o facebook aceitará um app android com o facebook4j?

Answer (score 1):

Alamo,

eu não sei responder exatamente sua pergunta. Mas eu uso o Android Simple Facebook, que é uma biblioteca que deixa transparente o uso do SDK do Facebook.

https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Na prática ele é uma camada entre sua aplicação e o SDK do Facebook.

Comment: Felipe. Obrigado. Vou tentar utilizar.